# I taught a lenient student about carbon - What's the hidden subject?

Tags: word, wordplay

Can you find the hidden subject of this message? Samples occur throughout the passage and there is a somewhat obvious clue included also.

> I want to help teenagers to pass the science test.
>   To do this, I taught a lenient student
>   About carbon. Are a few things made from it?
>   Learning about carbon is not something to knock, even if you'd rather go to the spa.
>   You'd wonder, could a spa get teenagers more interested in science?

I'm not 100% sure on what tags I should attach to the question, so I'll just mention that all that's required to solve this is simply to read it.

Comment: Entirely unrelated: In your profile riddle, aren't there THREE "locks"? ([rot13](http://rot13.com))pncf ybpx, fpebyy ybpx, naq ahz ybpx?

Comment: @Deusovi Whoops! You're absolutely right. That's embarrassing :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The secret subject is...

> pasta.

There's one related word in each line:

> **pass the**: pasta
>  **taught a leni**ent: tortellini
>  **carbon are a**: carbonara
>  **knock e**ven: gnocchi
>  **spa get tee**nagers: spaghetti

(The first two only work in some accents.)

Comment: Dammit I was editing >:<

Comment: And for another clue, look at the first letter of each line.

Comment: Huh, so either my pronunciation of English is wrong, or is my pronunciation of my native Italian.

Comment: @TobiaTesan: When we steal words, we change their pronunciations.

Comment: I know, I know, happens with every language. Still, I got a good chuckle out of it.

Comment: @TobiaTesan Which word is suspect to you? I cheated a bit with gnocci because I couldn't think of an English word that made the same sound as gn in italian

Comment: @hypern "Learning about carbon while E**nya kee**ps playing in the background." perhaps? ...assuming *my* Italian pronunciation is right ;p

Comment: I've never understood these pronunciation puzzles even looking at the answers (U.S. citizen in Great Lakes region). I could make a case for the first two only if Arnold Schwarzenegger were yelling them into a pillow.

Comment: Also, the answer is a well-known source of *carbo*hydrates.

Comment: @hypern Well, I don't pronounce any of those remotely like that. That's pretty much it. :)

Comment: @Sabre Nice try, I'd say more like "E**nyo kkee**ps" though. This is quite close, but I can't think of any English sound that is like the "gn" sound in gnocchi.

Answer (score 6):

New guess:

> Pasta

Hidden clue:

> Taking the first letter of every sentence, we get ITALY.

"Samples":

> I want to help teenagers to pass the science test.
> To do this, I **taught a leni**ent student --> Tortellini 
> About **carbon. Are a** few things made from it? --> Carbonara
>  
> Learning about carbon is not something to knock, even if you'd rather go to the spa.
> You'd wonder, could a **spa get tee**nagers more interested in science? --> Spaghetti

Comment: That's the included clue :)